# global settings php function

Tags: php, function

I'm busy developing a website where a blog is included. Now I'd like to add a dev_mode check. If I'm editing the article page, the check should return 'true' so I can publish a message like 'This page is currently being edited. Please come back later'. I want just ONE function for all the pages, but it's givin me no luck..

**My current function:**

```
function development_mode($mysqli, $dev_blog=false, $dev_article=false, $dev_cv=false, $dev_contact=false, $dev_bio=false, $dev_cpanel=false, $get_development_status=false) {
    $get_development_status = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM global_settings") or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $status = mysqli_fetch_array($get_development_status);
    $dev_blog = $status['dev_blog'];
    $dev_article = $status['dev_article'];
    $dev_cv = $status['dev_cv'];
    $dev_contact = $status['dev_contact'];
    $dev_bio = $status['dev_bio'];
    $dev_cpanel = $status['dev_cpanel'];

    if ($dev_blog == 'yes') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    if ($dev_article == 'yes') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    if ($dev_cv == 'yes') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    if ($dev_contact == 'yes') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    if ($dev_bio == 'yes') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    if ($dev_cpanel == 'yes') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**This is how I'd like to show the visitor the 'come back later' message when the article page is being edited**

```
if (development_mode($mysqli, $dev_article) == true) {
    echo "This page is being edited. Come back later!";
    die();
} else {
//Content
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry, we cannot _guess_ the logic you want to implement. You have to add more details to your question. But what strikes on first sight: The code after the first if/else statement will _never_ get executed, since the function _always_ returns inside that statement. Either giving true or false, but it will never continue to execute further down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work as expected for settings besides `dev_blog` because it does not take into consideration the value you pass to it as parameter, in your example `$dev_article`.

No matter what you try to pass to it, the page will ALWAYS execute the first `if`

```
if ($dev_blog == 'yes') {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

and return `true` or `false` depending on the setting `dev_blog` column returned by the query.

As is, execution will NEVER continue to check `$dev_article`, `$dev_contact`, `$dev_bio` or `$dev_cpanel` no matter what their values are or what parameters you try to pass to the `development_mode()` function.

---

**Solution:**

One way to check correctly would be to try something like below, calling the function using a string index of the columns:

```
 if (development_mode($mysqli, 'dev_article') == true) {
```

and then in your function have:

```
function development_mode($mysqli, $status_column) {
    $get_development_status = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM global_settings") or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $status = mysqli_fetch_array($get_development_status);

    $dev_status = $status[$status_column];

    if ($dev_status == 'yes') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

this could be even further optimized to return only the needed column since you only care about that one, but you get the point of what is different between the two.

Comment: I did not know that.. Seems like I have to create for every page a function, dont I? Thank you for your answer and explaination. Appreciated!

Comment: No worries, i updated the answer with a quick example on how you could implement a solution to that.